Solving set of linear integer equations, and we compute the automorphism subgroup of permuting variables (preserving equations)
Suppose we have a set of variables $X_i, i=1..n, n \in \Bbb{N}$ and a set $E$ of linear equations in them:
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda^j_i X_i = C_j \in \Bbb{Z} \\
j=1..m
$$
Then define $\textbf{Aut}(E) = \{ \sigma \in \textbf{Sym}(n) : \sigma E = E \}$ where $\sigma E$ action is applied to each equation, the equation is transformed by permuting the variables $X_{\sigma i}$ that occur within it.
So if $E^j \in E$ is $E_j: \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda^j_i X_i = C_j$, then $\sigma E_j :\sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda^j_{i} X_{\sigma i} = C_j$.
If and only if the two sets of equations $E = \{E_j:j=1..m\}$ and $\sigma E = \{\sigma E_j : j =1..m\}$ are exactly equal, we have that $\sigma \in \textbf{Aut}(E)$.
For example:
$$
E:= \{
A + B = 1 \\
B + C = 1\\
A + C = 2\}
$$
Then $\textbf{Aut}(E) \simeq \Bbb{Z}_2$ the cyclic group.  Because the only permutation you can make is $\sigma = (A,C)$ while preserving the set of equations.
Note that this also means that if $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$ is a solution then so is $\sigma X = (\sigma X_1, \dots, \sigma X_n)$.
Question.
Therefore I ask does knowing the equation's automorphism group cut down on the number of "possible solutions you need to check"?  Namely I'm imagining that $\Bbb{Z}_2$ would cut the solution checking difficulty in half.

Looking for more answers on this....

(Edited after first $6$ comments)
This answer is in the more general context of decision problems (notably the case of equation/inequation system solving), and optimization problems. The two kinds of problems, decision and optimization, are broadly equivalent, as finding an optimum can be done by finding solutions for a given objective value and refining this value by dichotomy; and on the other direction, a decision problem is an optimization problem with a constant objective function.
The word "complexity" here means the average run-time complexity, expressed as a function of the number of variables and constraints. One could refine by distinguishing average and worst-case run-time, as well as space complexity.
The efficiency of symmetries in reducing a problem complexity depends upon the available methods before and after considering these symmetries.
A first case is when the problem (without considering symmetries) has no better solving method than exhaustive search.
This may happen due to the constraints and objective function being highly non continuous, or unknown (e.g. being the result of complex computations). For a problem with discrete-valued variables, the solving strategy would be giving values to variables successively, thus exploring all value combinations in a tree.
For a problem with $N$ boolean variables, the complexity would be $2^{N-1}$. Note that whether or not there is a proof that the problem complexity is $2^{N-1}$, i.e. that there is no more efficient method, would not really be relevant in practice when implementing a solver for that problem.
In that case, having a symmetry such as $\mathbb Z_2$ can be used to cut in half the search space, hence dividing by $2$ the complexity of an exhaustive search. And in general if the orbit includes $P$ points, the complexity is divided by $P$.
For problems with continuously-valued variables, there needs to be some kind of regularity of the constraints and objective function, obviously. The "exhaustive search" would then be what comes under "black-box optimization". I have a feeling that the result would be similar as above: complexity is divided by the symmetry orbit size; but have no real argument to prove it.
Now on the case where there exists solving methods with a lower complexity than exhaustive search. For example, linear optimization: interior point methods have polynomial complexity (in the number of variables and constraints); simplex too has a polynomial complexity (proven for smoothed analysis), although its runtime can be exponential in some cases, i.e. its worst-case complexity is exponential.
Then having a symmetry is usually dealt with by adding constraints that reduce the search space to a domain where the solution is unique.
At first sight it seems we are complexifying the problem because we add a constraint. However the net effect is usually that some variables can be suppressed.
As an example, consider a linear optimization problem, where constraints and objective function are invariant by permutation of $Q$ variables (among a total of $N$ variables). We know that the optimum value is unique, and the set of points where optimum value is attained is convex. It is also invariant by permutation of the $Q$ variables, so it contains one point where all the $Q$ variables are equal. This can be used to suppress $Q-1$ variables from the problem.
We also know that complexity is polynomial, let's say $aN^k$ where $a$ and $k$ depend upon the method. After having supressed $Q-1$ variables, complexity is now $a(N-Q+1)^k$. We have reduced complexity, but not as much as we may have hoped.
For example, if we discretize the problem so as to be able to count, let's say each variable can take $v$ different values. The original domain size is $v^N$, and the reduced domain size after taking into account symmetries is $v^{N-Q+1}$. So domain size has been reduced by a $v^{Q-1}$ factor. However, complexity was $aN^k$ and is now $a(N-Q+1)^k$, which means it has been reduced by a $(\frac N {N-Q+1})^k$ factor.
This is a lot less. For example with $N=1000$, $Q=10$, $v=10$, $k=2$, domain size is reduced by a $10^9$ factor, while complexity is reduced by a $(\frac {1000} {991})^2 = 1.018$ factor, less than $2$ percents.
However in industrial problems, variables come in ranges (for example you may have variables indexed by timestep, product ID, etc.), and a given symmetry is usually replicated for all the values of one index. This creates a number of symmetries in the same order of magnitude as the number of variables, so the small $1.018$ factor above is elevated to a high exponent, and the overall complexity reduction can be great. But the automorphism group size is a lot greater than the complexity reduction factor.
There exist classes of problems and symmetries with better reduction factors than the general case above.
The Global Constraint Catalog (https://sofdem.github.io/gccat/) includes a number of such cases (as well as many other cases which are not symmetries per se, but nonetheless allow specific methods that reduce complexity). These cases are implemented in Constraint Programming solvers, and the efficiency of a problem modeling in one of those solvers critically depends upon the use of such global constraints.
However in the everyday life of industrial problems, it is quite rare to find applicable global constraints. And when finding one case, the model is brittle, i.e. any modification to the problem will usually break the global constraint. So models such as MILP that have a much larger applicability are preferred.

I don't understand this answer, breaking symmetries is a big topic in optimization, and it can cut down tremendously the search if the automorphism group is substantial...

I agree with you when the number of symmetries is (for example) in the same order of magnitude as the number of variables. Then you will usually introduce cuts so as to break symmetries. What I mean in the answer is that a single symmetry such as $\mathbb Z_2$ will not "cut the solution checking difficulty in half" (quoting the OP). I will modify my answer accordingly.

@Jean-ArmandMoroni you have not provided me any proof that the answer is indeed yes in the exhaustive search case.  Please explain why.  I'm not seeing how the automorphism group knowledge helps us out, but I got pretty far.  I just need help seeing why...

@Jean-ArmandMoroni PS, I don't like this answer either, they use Automorphisms to get quasi-polynomial graph isomorphism problems solved to the best degree possible.  And there is research into applying the symmetries to Linear Programming algorithms.

@Debug OK, I'll rewrite the answer today. For exhaustive search, I mean the case where there is no more efficient algorithm than random search of the domain (e.g. looking for zeroes of a highly discontinuous function). Then, by definition, dividing the search space by $N$ also divides the effort by $N$. On the other hand, for domains such as linear programming where efficient polynomial algorithms exist, taking symmetries into account does not reduce as well the effort: the algorithm complexity is $\log$ of the search space volume (polynomial complexity is $\log$ of exponential volume).

@Debug To look for how symmetries give rise to more efficient algorithms (for optimisation), the Global Constraint Catalog is a good source (https://sofdem.github.io/gccat/). In practice however, industrial problems rarely fit in one of these global constraints, so more general methods are used instead, such as MILP (mixed integer linear programming). (Symmetries may be used by pre-solve of MILP solvers, but if you model you problem in a "tight" way, the pre-solve will find very few simplifications).

In [1], the authors show how we can reduce the feasibility problem (and more generally the resolution of a linear program) to a reduced linear system with as many columns as variables orbits, and as many rows as constraints orbits.
They define an automorphism for a matrix $M$ as a pair of permutation matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that:
$$PM = MQ$$
They show that it is possible to rewrite this linear system in an equivalent linear system, which may be smaller in most cases.
For example, your matrix is here: $$M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&0\\
0&1&1\\
1&0&1\end{array}\right)$$
With the automorphism:
$$P = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&1\end{array}\right) ,Q = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\end{array}\right)$$
The eigenvectors of $Q$ are: $$\text{Vect}\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
1\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
0\end{array}\right) \right\}$$
We can aggregate variables of an orbit by averaging them. Here,you will replace the variables of orbit $\{A, C\}$ by the variable $D = \frac{A+C}{2}$. Here, your system rewrites as: $$\begin{cases}
D + B = 1 \\
2D = 2\end{cases}$$
(The first and second equations reduce to the same since these are in the same orbit). The feasibility of this linear system is equivalent to the original system. It is not clear how we can get back a generating set of vector for the original linear system, I guess there is an efficient way, but I have not cracked it.
The use of automorphisms is superseded by the work of [2], which show that the notion of fractional automorphism generalize the notion of automorphism, and gives essentially the same application. Furthermore, this notion of fractional automorphism is even more practical, since it is much more efficient to compute the coarsest partition (which is the equivalent of the orbit partition, but for fractional isomorphism), wich is done by the very simple colour refinement algorithm, than computing the orbits of the true automorphism group.
[1]: Herr, Katrin; Bödi, Richard, Symmetries in linear and integer programs, arXiv: Combinatorics, 2009.
[2]: Grohe, Martin; Kersting, Kristian; Mladenov, Martin; Selman, Erkal, Dimension reduction via colour refinement, Schulz, Andreas S. (ed.) et al., Algorithms – ESA 2014. 22nd annual European symposium, Wrocław, Poland, September 8–10, 2014. Proceedings. Berlin: Springer. Lect. Notes Comput. Sci. 8737, 505-516 (2014). ZBL1425.68313.
